# Abort previously made request on async ngx-typeahead

Tags: angular, asynchronous, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead, ngx-bootstrap

If I use in a component a [`ngx-typeahead`](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead) directive as below

```
<input type="search"
  [(ngModel)]="asyncSelected"
  [typeahead]="dataSource"
  (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)"
  (typeaheadNoResults)="changeTypeaheadNoResults($event)"
  (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
  [typeaheadWaitMs]="200"
  [typeaheadMinLength]="2"
  [typeaheadOptionsInScrollableView]="10"
  [typeaheadSingleWords]="false"
  [typeaheadScrollable]="true"
  [typeaheadItemTemplate]="someTemplate"
/>
```

With `dataSource` initiated in the component's constructor :

```
this.dataSource = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
    observer.next(this.asyncSelected);
}).mergeMap((token: string) => {
    return this.http.post<DevisResponses>('http://example.com/api',token);
});
```

When I'm writing in the `<input/>` some letters a *request A* will be made **200Ms** later, but **if I'm then quickly enter another letter before the end of the call** then I'll have a new *request B* with results mixed with the one from *request A* !

It seems that `[typeaheadWaitMs]` is the only parameter available to prevent a request, but **could I abort a previously made and unfinished request ?**

Comment: Use `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap`.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks, when looking [at the doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) it seems great but I've got an ``Observable_1.Observable.create(...).switchMap is not a function``

Comment: Maybe you didnt import switchMap operator?

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk I didn't import ``mergeMap`` either but it's working out of the box. I tried to import via ``import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';`` but without success ! (same error)

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk && @DanielB I now understand why it didn't work, I had to ``.pipe()`` the created ``Observable `` like ``).pipe(switchMap(``

Comment: @DanielB would you like to post an answer to that question that I could mark as accepted ?

Comment: Will do, give me a few!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as [@Daniel B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447173/daniel-b) and [@Alexander Poshtaruk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6528560/alexander-poshtaruk) pointed in their comments, I had to import the `swithMap` operator and use it instead of `mergeMap` because, as stated in [the doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap) :

> When a new inner Observable is emitted, switchMap stops emitting items from the earlier-emitted inner Observable and begins emitting items from the new one.

So after `import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';` here's how I initiate `dataSource` now:

```
this.dataSource = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
    observer.next(this.asyncSelected);
}).mergeMap((token: string) => {
    return this.http.post<DevisResponses>('http://example.com/api',token);
});
```

But still, I don't understand why can't I use `.switchMap` as a method of the created `Observable` (as written in [the doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap) example)